# retrieving ParseObject from Parse.com with given object id failed

Tags: android, parse-platform, cloud, backend

i do this in my onCreate method:

```
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this);
    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("Becky", "is dumb");
    testObject.put("SammyHuang", "is smart");
    testObject.saveInBackground();
```

then i have a button does this:

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("SammyHuang");
  query.getInBackground("2wTGHJ230q", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // object will be your game score
      becky = object.getString("Becky");
      sammy = object.getString("SammyHuang");
      System.out.println(sammy);
    }
  else {
      System.out.println("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbruh");
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

i copy the object id "2wTGHJ230q" from the parse website and tried to get it display in terminal but overtime i run it it prints "bruh", i can't figure what went wrong. thx in advanced.

edit:
i fix the getQuery("SammyHuang") to getQuery("TestObject"), it still prints "bruh".

re edit:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private String sammy;
  private String becky;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // [Optional] Power your app with Local Datastore. For more info, go to
    // https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#local-datastore


    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("Becky", "is dumb");
    testObject.put("SammyHuang", "is smart");
    testObject.saveInBackground();
  }


  public void helloFunc(View view){
    final TextView lol = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.moron);
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TestObject");

    query.getInBackground("u2VE9tIAwA", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
      public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
          becky = new String(object.getString("Becky"));
          sammy = new String(object.getString("SammyHuang"));
        } else {
          System.out.println("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbruh");
          e.printStackTrace();
          System.out.println("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbruh");
          // something went wrong
        }
      }
    });
    lol.setText("becky " + becky + "\n" + "sammy " + sammy);

  }
}
```

i don't know why the lol.setText give me null. seems like assign the variable "becky" and "sammy" within the method getinbackground is not working. and also i am confused about how can this method has a parameter that is a object with another method define within it.

Comment: `System.out.println(e.printStackTrace());` it will show you error in log

Answer (score 0):

You save the object as a `TestObject` (when you do `new ParseObject("TestObject")`) so you also need to retrieve it as one by doing `ParseQuery.getQuery("TestObject")`.

I think it would be a good idea for you to check the Parse documentation on [saving](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-saving-objects) and [retrieving](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-retrieving-objects) objects.

And in case you run into an error again, make sure to check the message of the ParseError, as it usually contains a great deal of information that can help you find the issue.

Comment: thx for your suggestion but after i did what you suggested but it does not work. i add the stack trace in my question, still not sure how to fix it, maybe u can tell me?

Comment: Did you include your application id and client key in the manifest file, as explained on https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing ?

Comment: Hmm, it seems like Parse is able to store the object, but is not initialized when you try to fetch the object. Could you post your entire `onCreate` method and the setup of the button click listener?

Comment: i did what u ask, but i think its the gradle thing that make it crash. i don't know why i follow the parse guide crash my app.

Comment: Wild guess: Can you try calling `setContentView` after the Parse initialization?

Comment: Great! It's probably because the click listener is initialized when the content is inflated, and thus Parse is using an uninitialized object in the click listener. I'm just guessing here, I can't actually figure it out exactly without the code, but that's what it seems like.

Comment: and also, the second parameter for the function "getInBackground" seems like a object with a defined function. after i get the string i want to use the textview"lol" to display the retrieve result. but i can't do it..

Comment: Can't do it - why not?

Comment: I think you should either be more descriptive in your comment, or create a brand new question, as it seems like your original question has been solved, and it could be extremely confusing for other people reading this when we start mixing up questions.